# How can I get the "volume up" button to function as the camera shutter when using a custom overlay with Titanium.Media.showCamera()?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I have a custom overlay view created in Titanium that I'm using with the Titanium.Media.showCamera() API like this:

```
Ti.Media.showCamera({
    success: function() {},
    cancel: function() {},
    error: function() {},
    overlay: myOverlayView,
    showControls: false,
    autohide: false,
    mediaTypes: [Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO],
});
```

This is working fine...EXCEPT that now the "volume up" physical button on the iPhone does not function as a camera shutter anymore.  With the built-in controls (showControls: true) when I press the volume up button it snaps a photo.

I'd like to have that also be the case with my custom overlay.  I have tried listening for the [Ti.Media volume event](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Media-event-volume), but it's never fired when the camera overlay is visible.